# MS Azure PowerShell - The subscription name doesn't exist

Tags: powershell, azure, default, subscription

I try to run some commands in Azure PowerShell. My problem is to set the default subscription to execute several commands.

```
Login-AzureRmAccount # sign in with azure account is ok

New-AzureWebSiteJob -Name 'MyApp1' -JobName 'GetDate' -JobType Continuous -JobFile '.\Job.zip'
```

output is:

> No default subscription has been designated. Use
>   Select-AzureSubscription -Default  to set the 
>   default subscription.

I try to set the default subscription:

```
Select-AzureSubscription -Default -SubscriptionName 'Pay-As-You-Go'
```

output :

> The subscription name Pay-As-You-Go doesn't exist.

I try use 'RM' command: `Select-AzureRMSubscription -SubscriptionName 'Pay-As-You-Go'` 
output is ok:

```
Environment           : AzureCloud
Account               : peter111@gmail.com
TenantId              : 6348f153-a363-32c9-b7a0-1abad0e3fc23
SubscriptionId        : c56d4caf-2095-3c0e-8fca-6db2cd3bd06b
SubscriptionName      : Pay-As-You-Go
```

I try to set the default subscription with 'RM' command:

```
Select-AzureRMSubscription -Default -SubscriptionName 'Pay-As-You-Go'
```

output:

> Set-AzureRmContext : A parameter cannot be found that matches
>   parameter name 'Default'.

How can I set the default subscription?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the `New-AzureWebSiteJob` cmdlet you have to authenticate using the `Add-AzureAccount` cmdlet. Then you are able to select the default subscription using `Select-AzureSubscription`.

Comment: Thanks very much ... its running

Answer (score 0):

> Set-AzureRmContext : A parameter cannot be found that matches
>   parameter name 'Default'.

Please try this command without 'Default':

```
Select-AzureRMSubscription -SubscriptionName 'Pay-As-You-Go'
```

Comment: It returns full account identiication but not set subscription as Default

Comment: He wants to use the `New-AzureWebSiteJob` cmdlet so anything related to *RM* probably is obsolete here, isn't it?